# WiFi on-off widget...Unreachable code

Tags: java, android, widget

I'm trying to make a simple widget for the first time using some online tutorials and some decompiled code I found online. But I'm having trouble with this method below. I get error Unreachable code.

```
private void Update(Context paramContext, AppWidgetManager paramAppWidgetManager, int[] paramArrayOfInt)
      {
        RemoteViews localRemoteViews = new RemoteViews(paramContext.getPackageName(), R.xml.widget);
        WifiManager localWifiManager = (WifiManager)paramContext.getSystemService("wifi");
        try
        {
          int i = localWifiManager.getWifiState();
          if (i == 3)
          {
            localRemoteViews.setImageViewResource(R.xml.widget, R.drawable.off);
            link(localRemoteViews, paramContext, paramAppWidgetManager);
            if ((paramArrayOfInt == null) || (paramArrayOfInt.length <= 0))
              break;
            paramAppWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(paramArrayOfInt, localRemoteViews);
          }
          while (true)
          {
            return;
            if (i == 1)
            {
              localRemoteViews.setImageViewResource(R.xml.widget, R.drawable.on);
              break;
            }
            localRemoteViews.setImageViewResource(R.xml.widget, R.drawable.off);
            break;
            paramAppWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(this.THIS_WIDGET, localRemoteViews);
          }
        }
        catch (Exception localException)
        {
          break;
        }
      }
```

This is the whole class:

```
package com.wifiswitch.bestwifiswitch;

import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.appwidget.AppWidgetManager;
import android.appwidget.AppWidgetProvider;
import android.content.ComponentName;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.wifi.WifiManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.RemoteViews;

public class WifiWidget extends AppWidgetProvider {

    static final String THIS_INTENT = "com.wifiswitch.bestwifiswitch.toggle";
    final ComponentName THIS_WIDGET = new ComponentName("com.wifiswitch.bestwifiswitch", "com.wifiswitch.bestwifiswitch.WifiWidget");

    private void Toggle(Context paramContext, String paramString)
      {
        if ("com.wifiswitch.bestwifiswitch.toggle".equals(paramString))
        {
          WifiManager localWifiManager = (WifiManager)paramContext.getSystemService("wifi");
          try
          {
            int i = localWifiManager.getWifiState();
            if (i == 3)
              localWifiManager.setWifiEnabled(false);
            else if (i == 1)
              localWifiManager.setWifiEnabled(true);
          }
          catch (Exception localException)
          {
          }
        }
      }

    private void Update(Context paramContext, AppWidgetManager paramAppWidgetManager, int[] paramArrayOfInt)
      {
        RemoteViews localRemoteViews = new RemoteViews(paramContext.getPackageName(), R.xml.widget);
        WifiManager localWifiManager = (WifiManager)paramContext.getSystemService("wifi");
        try
        {
          int i = localWifiManager.getWifiState();
          if (i == 3)
          {
            localRemoteViews.setImageViewResource(R.xml.widget, R.drawable.off);
            link(localRemoteViews, paramContext, paramAppWidgetManager);
            if ((paramArrayOfInt == null) || (paramArrayOfInt.length <= 0))
              break;
            paramAppWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(paramArrayOfInt, localRemoteViews);
          }
          while (true)
          {
            return;
            if (i == 1)
            {
              localRemoteViews.setImageViewResource(R.xml.widget, R.drawable.on);
              break;
            }
            localRemoteViews.setImageViewResource(R.xml.widget, R.drawable.off);
            break;
            paramAppWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(this.THIS_WIDGET, localRemoteViews);
          }
        }
        catch (Exception localException)
        {
          break;
        }
      }

    private void link(RemoteViews paramRemoteViews, Context paramContext, AppWidgetManager paramAppWidgetManager)
      {
        Intent localIntent = new Intent("com.wifiswitch.bestwifiswitch.toggle");
        localIntent.setComponent(this.THIS_WIDGET);
        paramRemoteViews.setOnClickPendingIntent(2131099648, PendingIntent.getBroadcast(paramContext, 0, localIntent, 0));
      }

    public void onReceive(Context paramContext, Intent paramIntent)
      {
        String str = paramIntent.getAction();
        if ("android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_UPDATE".equals(str))
        {
          Bundle localBundle = paramIntent.getExtras();
          if (localBundle != null)
          {
            int[] arrayOfInt = localBundle.getIntArray("appWidgetIds");
            if ((arrayOfInt != null) && (arrayOfInt.length > 0))
              onUpdate(paramContext, AppWidgetManager.getInstance(paramContext), arrayOfInt);
          }
        }
        while (true)
        {
          return;
          if ("com.wifiswitch.bestwifiswitch.toggle".equals(str))
          {
            Toggle(paramContext, "com.roundedlabs.widgets.wifi.toggle");
            Update(paramContext, AppWidgetManager.getInstance(paramContext), null);
          }
          else
          {
            Update(paramContext, AppWidgetManager.getInstance(paramContext), null);
          }
        }
      }

    public void onUpdate(Context paramContext, AppWidgetManager paramAppWidgetManager, int[] paramArrayOfInt)
      {
        Update(paramContext, paramAppWidgetManager, paramArrayOfInt);
      }




}
```

Answer (score -1):

One problem is with the break statement in `onUpdate` method. break statement will break a loop or switch statement. In your code, you need be return from the method. So, change the break as return.

Other problem is with `onUpdate` and `onReceive` method. If while(true) your returning , this will break the loop and return , so that the next statements will not be reached. You need to remove the return statement here or change your logic to return based on any condition.

```
while (true)
{
  return;
  if ("com.wifiswitch.bestwifiswitch.toggle".equals(str))
  {
            Toggle(paramContext, "com.roundedlabs.widgets.wifi.toggle");
            Update(paramContext, AppWidgetManager.getInstance(paramContext), null);
  }
```